# Where is the template for page that forwards to payment system? (frontend/base/default/template/ops/placeform.phtml)

Tags: template, payment

We are using Concardis to handle our credit card payments. After checkout, there is a page that notifies the user they are being forwarded to Concardis for payment. However, it is set to use a 3-column layout when I want to switch it to 1-column as well as edit the template.

I turned on block/path hints and see that it says the page is:

```
frontend/base/default/template/ops/placeform.phtml
```

The corresponding URL is:

```
http://domain.com/ops/payment/placeform/
```

However, I see no such file. (I would want to copy this file to my template and do some edits, but also I'm wondering how to even choose the template to begin with)

Comment: Enable template path hints and you should find its exact location

Comment: @Marius I noted in my question that I used the hints to find the path and there is no such file – But I now realized that the folder must be on the server having been installed by a plugin, so I synced my local copy and found the files :) Now just wondering *how to change the layout from 3-column to 1-column* :) I know it must be something related to layout XML, but not sure how to target this page in my local.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the layout handle `<ops_payment_placeform>` in the module layout file and add this inside it

```
<update handle="page_one_column" />
```

And clear the cache.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you :) Just for my understanding, does the xml layout typically follow this rule? folder/folder/filename -> folder_folder_filename

Comment: Usually yes. There are some other handles loaded in special cases but this will always be loaded.